# Checking HTML5 drag and drop file type

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'd like to change drop zone background color to green or red depending on whether the contained drag over payload contains supported file types (JPEG).

- Do Gecko and Webkit support determining the file type of drag and drop files?
- How one can extract the file type in these two browsers?

I have found event.dataTransfer.types API, but for Firefox it seems to be populated with **application/x-moz-file** and thus I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Should work in Gecko, WebKit restricts access to the data transfer object on drag over.  What code do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the file types in Gecko and webkit supported browsers using file object.

```
var files =e.dataTransfer.files||e.target.files; // File list
```

The file object returns Name,Type and size. you can get last modified date too.

```
var mimeType= files[0].type; //mime type of file list first entry
```

Comment: Why || e.target.files fallback? Does it take into account some unexpected case or something?

Comment: Note that this MIME type is generated using the file extension (i.e. the .gif or .jpeg at the end of the filename.) This is definitively not going to be the real type of the file in all cases. Many people will put .jpg when they save a PNG or BMP file... because they know .jpg means "image".

Comment: @AlexisWilke, I think your case is an extreme corner case.  Most people when saving a file dont type the extension (or it is hidden) in windows.  But more importantly, I doubt most programs have fallback detection to figure out the filetype from the data itself when the extension doesnt match.  E.g. adding .jpg at the end of a png file and trying to open it in photoshop (the #1 photo editor) leads to photoshop throwing an error that it is an invlaid jpg.  If you have extension detection, and the user changes it to the wrong one, then that is their issue, not yours. Crap in, Crap out.

Comment: @ChrisJanssen at the same time, we are talking about files that will be sent by person A to server B which then serves that same file to person C...

Comment: And why is the filetype changing along that path?  Every OS uses the filetype to determine what a file is and what the appropriate program to open it with, it doesn't parse the beginning data to make that decision, it trusts that the filetype wasn't changed.  In most cases it warns the user not to change a filetype as it may stop functioning.  Why not just keep it simple and check the filetype?

Comment: I am trying to do that with a dragenter event in the last version of Firefox but files is null...

Answer (score 8):

Testing the type of a file in JavaScript is a bit of work, but new versions of the browsers now have the `FileReader` object that allows you to do that.

Here is an incomplete reference to my implementation which reads the buffer as uint8 bytes and then checks to see whether the input is a valid JPEG, GIF, PNG. Obviously, it will be enhanced with time. For a more complete version, look for the [`editor.js` file in the editor and the mimetype plugins of the *snapwebsites* project](https://github.com/m2osw/snapwebsites/tree/main/snapserver-core-plugins/src).

```
// The buffer is expected to be an ArrayBuffer() as read with a FileReader
_buffer2mime: function(buffer)
{
    buf = Uint8Array(buffer);
    if(buf[0] == 0xFF
    && buf[1] == 0xD8
    && buf[2] == 0xFF
    && buf[3] == 0xE0
    && buf[4] == 0x00
    && buf[5] == 0x10
    && buf[6] == 0x4A  // J
    && buf[7] == 0x46  // F
    && buf[8] == 0x49  // I
    && buf[9] == 0x46) // F
    {
        return "image/jpeg";
    }
    if(buf[0] == 0x89
    && buf[1] == 0x50  // P
    && buf[2] == 0x4E  // N
    && buf[3] == 0x47  // G
    && buf[4] == 0x0D  // \r
    && buf[5] == 0x0A) // \n
    {
        return "image/png";
    }
    if(buf[0] == 0x47  // G
    && buf[1] == 0x49  // I
    && buf[2] == 0x46  // F
    && buf[3] == 0x38  // 8
    && buf[4] == 0x39  // 9
    && buf[5] == 0x61) // a
    {
        return "image/gif";
    }

    // unknown
    return "";
},

_droppedImageAssign: function(e){
    var img,id;
    img = new Image();
    img.src = e.target.result;
    ++this._uniqueId;
    id="snap-editor-image-"+this._uniqueId;
    jQuery(img).hide().attr("id",id).appendTo(e.target.snapEditorElement);
    jQuery("#"+id).show();
},

_droppedImage: function(e){
    var mime, r, a, blob;

    mime = snapwebsites.EditorInstance._buffer2mime(e.target.result);
    if(mime.substr(0, 6) == "image/")
    {
        r = new FileReader;
        r.snapEditorElement = e.target.snapEditorElement;
        r.onload = snapwebsites.EditorInstance._droppedImageAssign;
        a = [];
        a.push(e.target.snapEditorFile);
        blob = new Blob(a, {type: mime}); // <- FORCE THE REAL MIME TYPE
        r.readAsDataURL(blob);
    }
},

jQuery("#some-object")
        .on("drop",function(e){
            // always prevent the default dropping mechanism
            // we handle the file manually all the way
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // anything transferred on widget that accepts files?
            if(e.originalEvent.dataTransfer
            && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length)
            {
                accept_images = jQuery(this).hasClass("image");
                accept_files = jQuery(this).hasClass("attachment");
                if(accept_images || accept_files)
                {
                    for(i = 0; i < e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files.length; ++i)
                    {
                        // read the image so we can make sure it is indeed an
                        // image and ignore any other type of files
                        r = new FileReader;
                        r.snapEditorElement = this;
                        r.snapEditorFile = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[i];
                        r.onload = snapwebsites.EditorInstance._droppedImage;
                        // Get the first 64 bytes of the file to check the magic code
                        r.readAsArrayBuffer(r.snapEditorFile.slice(0, 64));
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can rely on the browser to give you the MIME type. It'd be much simpler if you checked the filename extension. :)

If you really want to check the file type, read the payload using `DataTransfer.getData()` and check the leading bytes (`PNG`, `GIF89`, `JFIF` or something).

Comment: So you really think that the filename extension is a more trustworthy indication of the file type??? Checking the data is the only real way to make sure. The file magic as it's called.