# Jquery validate file ext on upload

Tags: jquery

I have a page for allowing users to upload their images using drag and drop and I would like to restrict them to uploading jpg files only.

I have to admit I am a complete newbie when it comes to jquery so I really don't have a clue how to make this work.

So far I have

```
var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
var ext = $('#drop-files').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();


// Show the upload holder
$('#uploaded-holder').show();

// For each file
$.each(files, function(index, file) {
    if($.inArray(ext, ['JPG','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
           alert('invalid extension!');
           return false;
       }
```

As this is it does nothing, if I remove the 'return false' it tells me every file is invalid and uploads them anyway.

Thanks

btw, I am aware that there are unclosed brackets, I'm just hoping the someone will see something obvious I have missed out in the section of code I've supplied

Comment: If you really want to check the file type, read the payload using DataTransfer.getData() and check the leading bytes (PNG, GIF89, JFIF or something). [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091766/checking-html5-drag-and-drop-file-type)

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, nope, no error

Comment: @f00bar - thanks for that but I have absolutely no idea what that means! lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are returning `false` from the function within the `each` loop, not the submit handler function. Try this:

```
// For each file
var validExtension = false;
$.each(files, function(index, file) {
    if ($.inArray(ext, ['JPG','jpg','jpeg']) != -1 && !validExtension) {
        validExtension = true;
    }
}
return validExtension;
```

Comment: HI thanks for that, not sure why though, but it flags a syntax error after the return in Dreamweaver?